# BorderLayout correct syntax

Tags: java, swing, syntax, border-layout

as far as i know the syntax of the add method is

```
add(Component , String);
```

ex.

```
add(new Button("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

but i saw that syntax of the add method in a class and it passses the compilation proccess.

```
add(String , Component);
```

and it was the below add method :

```
add("North", new Button("North"));
```

Can someone explain me what happened here and if is this going to work and why ?

Comment: did you check the API ???

Comment: "if is this going to work" did you try?

Comment: i tried and it worked but i dont know why it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has shown in the Java Doc, the Container class has [5 different add() methods overloads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html)

In your first example, BorderLayout.NORTH is a constant defining the position of your component in the Container.

In your second example, "North" is the name you give to your component.

Answer (score 1):

The method `add(Component , Object);` adds a component, with the contraints specified in the second parameter. The `BorderLayout` class uses `String` instances for the constraints, but other layouts use other object types. For instance, the `GridBagLayout` uses an instance of `GridBagContraints`.

The method `add(String , Component);` adds a component with its name as the first parameter.